# Alternatives to plaster veneer?

Tags: lath-and-plaster, rock-lath

I need to close up a window hole (that was on a formerly exterior wall and after an addition, turned into shelving).

Apparently plaster veneer is unknown in my parts, but it'd be a perfect solution to match the existing rock lack/plaster the rest of the walls have.

What should I look at for alternatives? I have a little experience drywall mudding, but far from a pro. (This patch is pretty well hidden so results don't need to be perfect.)

Comment: Can you put a picture of the desired effect? Does the former hole face the outside and needs to be insulated?

Comment: If the patch is hidden and doesn't need to be perfect, it sounds like a great opportunity for you to practice your plaster veneer skills and go into business providing a much needed service to your local area.

Comment: @bobflux just looking for a relatively smooth surface that wouldnt standout too much from the rest of the plaster in the house. The hole/shelving unit faces the addition, so its now an interior hole (so no need to insulate).

Comment: @FreeMan im always looking to craft new skills (but to make this one marketable? Probably not in my skillset haha). Do you know if theres any other product aside from the dedicated plaster veneer that would work as plaster veneer?